# Solving (non-linear) recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence relation $x_{n+1} \le x_{n-\tau} - a\cdot x_{n-\tau}^2 + b$ where $\tau$ is some positive integer, I'm not sure how to approach it. An upper bound will be enough [my hope is that $x_n \le O(1/n)$].

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\tau?$

Comment: some constant (I'll edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $x_n \equiv \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$ satisfies your relation, so unless there is something you are not telling us your hypothesis does not seem to hold.

Comment: I see, to bad... Thanks!